# Setblocking GUI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a really cool MC map for java and I was wondering as I was making some kind of firework show, is it possible using commands to setblock GUI blocks that have stuff in them?

For Example, Dispensers with fireworks?

If not is there a way to place normal dispensers, Then fill them with fireworks.

who gives answers will get my map for free!

Comment: Of course, with NBT: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format

Comment: THANK YOU, but can you make the firework rockets in the dispenser be specific, for instance setblock ~ ~ ~ dispenser {id:firework_rockets{Color:Green,type=red_ball} ?

Comment: Sure, you can do tons of things. I would recommend just doing the thing manually once (like putting in the item) and then running `/data get` on the block and taking the elements you need from there.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it. When I am done il make sure to send you a copy of the map for your help

Comment: hey, Fabian, I am in the alpha stages of the map, and I know that you helped a lot so id like to send you a copy of it and hear some suggestions and thoughts and like to have you be the first tester. Send me an  email so i know to send it to you. Send me an email at              "xshadowshooterx915@gmail.com"

Comment: My contact info is in my profile. Make sure whether you actually want that mail address to be public, because that comment is public.

Comment: yea, it's ok. I will make sure to send it to you by 15.5.2020 10 pm GMT, probably even shorter

Comment: BTW, This is IMPORTANT, the map can only be opened in MINECRAFT 1.16 snapshot 20w20a.

Comment: Please leave comments for their intended purpose: Clearing up parts of the question, asking and answering clarifying questions, handling stuff related to the question, etc. Not general conversation. Chat exists and I already told you where to find my contact info.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to manually type out the items that are to be in the dispenser, it would be a very long command and hard to make sense of.

If you can, try placing a "template" dispenser on the ground filled with fireworks, and using `/clone` to clone it to the desired position.

For example:
Full dispenser wanted at XYZ (10, 11, 12)
Template dispenser placed at XYZ (1, 2, 3)
The command to use is:

```
/clone 1 2 3 1 2 3 10 11 12
```

Make sure that the dispenser faces the same way you want it to face when placed in its new position!